# how to replace NULL values in pivot table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I try to create a pivot table which only includes strings.

This is a simple version of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE SecurityGroup (GroupName VARCHAR(20), SecLevel VARCHAR(20),       Power VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO SecurityGroup 
SELECT 'GroupA','Level1','read'
UNION
SELECT 'GroupA','Level2','write'  
UNION
SELECT 'GroupA','Level3','read'  
UNION
SELECT 'GroupA','Level4','read'  
UNION
SELECT 'GroupA','Level4','write'
```

I want to use the PIVOT function to get the following Resultset

**Expectation**

```
GroupName    Level1    Level2    Level3    Level4
GroupA       read      write     read      read
GroupA       read      write     read      write
```

The problem I have is that the values for Level1 - Level3 only exist 1 time, while Level4 has 2 different values. So I'm always getting this Resultset:

**Reality**

```
GroupName    Level1    Level2    Level3    Level4
GroupA       read      write     read      read
GroupA       NULL      NULL      NULL      write
```

I'm using this code

```
SELECT 
 [GroupName],
 [Level1],
 [Level2],
 [Level3],
 [Level4]
FROM 
 (SELECT
 [GroupName],
 [SecLevel], 
 [Power],
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [GroupName], [SecLevel] ORDER BY [Power]) AS    rn
FROM [SecurityGroup]) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
 (MAX([Power])
  FOR [SecLevel] 
  IN ([Level1], [Level2], [Level3], [Level4])
 ) AS PivotTable
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I can not add more values for Level1 - Level3 in the source table.

I already tried to use RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER() but it didnt work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A pain to write, but my idea is to use a CTE or temp table in which you do add values for Level1 - Level3, and then select from the CTE instead of the table.   The actual table need not be changed.   There ought to be something more elegant, but I'm not coming up with it.

Comment: looking at the input result set your PIVOT is returning the correct result! you essentially have two different groups albeit that they are both named GroupA. one has a value for all 4 levels and one has only for level 4.

Comment: btw, why are you generating a RowNumber and not using it anywhere?

Comment: I have to use RowNumber to seperate the values "read" and "write" for Level4. Otherwise I will only get 1 line in the Resultset which includes the value MAX(Power) .... in my case "write".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 [GroupName],
 MAX([Level1]) OVER (PARTITION BY [GroupName]) [Level1],
 MAX([Level2]) OVER (PARTITION BY [GroupName]) [Level2],
 MAX([Level3]) OVER (PARTITION BY [GroupName]) [Level3],
 [Level4]
FROM 
 (SELECT
 [GroupName],
 [SecLevel], 
 [Power],
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [GroupName], [SecLevel] ORDER BY [Power]) AS    rn
FROM [SecurityGroup]) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
 (MAX([Power])
  FOR [SecLevel] 
  IN ([Level1], [Level2], [Level3], [Level4])
 ) AS PivotTable;
```